# Clean MongoDB/Node.js/Express code and routes

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb, express, routes

I started learning database with MongoDB and Node.js not long ago and I'm trying to find a way to use Express routes **without** mongoose. I want to insert data using Express routes and have clean code exporting different modules. The problem is that i can't write routes
as below because in my index.js file "db" is of course not defined and apparently i can't insert data into my "db" outside of the function "client.connect" as with mongoose. Do i have to connect my db in a file with all my posts or is there a specific way to do it? (sorry for my English, I'm learning it).

App.js :

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const expressLayouts = require('express-ejs-layouts');
const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
const assert = require('assert');

//EJS
app.use(expressLayouts);
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

//Styles
app.use('/public', express.static('public'));

//Bodyparser
app.use(express.urlencoded({extended: false}));


//Connect to DB
const url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/shopping'
const dbName = 'shopping';
const client = new MongoClient(url);

client.connect((err)=>{
    assert.equal(null, err);
    console.log('connected to db...');

    app.use('/', require('./routes/index'));    

    const db = client.db(dbName);
});

//Server
app.listen(3000, ()=>{console.log("Listening to port 3000")});
```

index.js (routes):

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

//Get home page
router.get('/', (req, res)=>{
    res.render('shop/index')
});

router.get('/posts', (req,res)=>{
    res.render('posts')
});

router.post('/posts',(req,res)=>{
    db.collection('users').insertOne({'name': req.name, 'password': req.password});
});

module.exports = router;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Index.js should include a function with which to pass your mongo client in. So for example:

```
let mongoClient
router.passMongoClient = function(clientIn){
   mongoClient = clientIn
}
```

Then after you've started your client, pass it in through your new function

```
const router = require(./router)

client.connect((err)=>{
    assert.equal(null, err);
    console.log('connected to db...');

    app.use('/', require('./routes/index'));    
    const db = client.db(dbName);
    router.passMongoClient(db)
});
```

This is the basic idea. You may wish to structure your code a little differently. I wait to start my http server until I get the callback from the mongodb client that it's connected. Depends on your use case to a degree.

Comment: Thank you! I think i understood.